# When and how often CALL apoc.warmup.run() Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I read using `CALL apoc.warmup.run()` is supposed to load all pages into cache for faster querying.

Is it enough to `CALL` this function once after DB startup? Or should this APOC CALL be used differently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just once after startup is enough.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom